# mpi4py Gatherv facing KeyError: '0'

Tags: parallel-processing, openmpi, mpi4py

I am new in mpi4py. I wrote the code in order to process a large numpy array `data` by multiple processor. As I am unable to provide the input file I am mentioning the shape of `data`. Shape of `data` is [3000000,15] and it contains string type of data.

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import math as math


comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
numprocs = comm.size
rank = comm.Get_rank()
fname = "6.binetflow"
data = np.loadtxt(open(fname,"rb"), dtype=object, delimiter=",", skiprows=1)
X = data[:,[0,1,3,14,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6]]
num_rows = math.ceil(len(X)/float(numprocs))
X = X.flatten()
sendCounts = list()
displacements = list()
for p in range(numprocs):
    if p == (numprocs-1): #for last processor
        sendCounts.append(int(len(X) - (p*num_rows*12)))
        displacements.append(int(p*num_rows*12))
        break
    sendCounts.append(int(num_rows*12))
    displacements.append(int(p*sendCounts[p]))
sendbuf = np.array(X[displacements[rank]: (displacements[rank]+sendCounts[rank])])

## Each processor will do some task on sendbuf

if rank == 0:
    recvbuf = np.empty(sum(sendCounts), dtype=object)
else:
    recvbuf = None

print("sendbuf: ",sendbuf)
comm.Gatherv(sendbuf=sendbuf, recvbuf=(recvbuf, sendCounts), root=0)
if rank == 0:
    print("Gathered array: {}".format(recvbuf))
```

But I am facing below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 36, in <module>
    comm.Gatherv(sendbuf=sendbuf, recvbuf=(recvbuf, sendCounts), root=0)
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 602, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Gatherv (d:\build\mpi4py\mpi4py-2.0.0\src\mpi4py.MPI.c:97993)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 525, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_gather (d:\build\mpi4py\mpi4py-2.0.0\src\mpi4py.MPI.c:34678)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 446, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_cco_send (d:\build\mpi4py\mpi4py-2.0.0\src\mpi4py.MPI.c:33938)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 148, in mpi4py.MPI.message_simple (d:\build\mpi4py\mpi4py-2.0.0\src\mpi4py.MPI.c:30349)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 93, in mpi4py.MPI.message_basic (d:\build\mpi4py\mpi4py-2.0.0\src\mpi4py.MPI.c:29448)
KeyError: 'O'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 36, in <module>
    comm.Gatherv(sendbuf=sendbuf, recvbuf=(recvbuf, sendCounts), root=0)
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 602, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Gatherv (d:\build\mpi4py\mpi4py-2.0.0\src\mpi4py.MPI.c:97993)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 525, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_gather (d:\build\mpi4py\mpi4py-2.0.0\src\mpi4py.MPI.c:34678)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 446, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_cco_send (d:\build\mpi4py\mpi4py-2.0.0\src\mpi4py.MPI.c:33938)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 148, in mpi4py.MPI.message_simple (d:\build\mpi4py\mpi4py-2.0.0\src\mpi4py.MPI.c:30349)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 93, in mpi4py.MPI.message_basic (d:\build\mpi4py\mpi4py-2.0.0\src\mpi4py.MPI.c:29448)
KeyError: 'O'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 36, in <module>
    comm.Gatherv(sendbuf=sendbuf, recvbuf=(recvbuf, sendCounts), root=0)
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 602, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Gatherv (d:\build\mpi4py\mpi4py-2.0.0\src\mpi4py.MPI.c:97993)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 525, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_gather (d:\build\mpi4py\mpi4py-2.0.0\src\mpi4py.MPI.c:34678)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 446, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_cco_send (d:\build\mpi4py\mpi4py-2.0.0\src\mpi4py.MPI.c:33938)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 148, in mpi4py.MPI.message_simple (d:\build\mpi4py\mpi4py-2.0.0\src\mpi4py.MPI.c:30349)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 93, in mpi4py.MPI.message_basic (d:\build\mpi4py\mpi4py-2.0.0\src\mpi4py.MPI.c:29448)
KeyError: 'O'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 36, in <module>
    comm.Gatherv(sendbuf=sendbuf, recvbuf=(recvbuf, sendCounts), root=0)
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 602, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Gatherv (d:\build\mpi4py\mpi4py-2.0.0\src\mpi4py.MPI.c:97993)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 516, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_gather (d:\build\mpi4py\mpi4py-2.0.0\src\mpi4py.MPI.c:34587)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 466, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_cco_recv (d:\build\mpi4py\mpi4py-2.0.0\src\mpi4py.MPI.c:34097)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 261, in mpi4py.MPI.message_vector (d:\build\mpi4py\mpi4py-2.0.0\src\mpi4py.MPI.c:31977)
  File "MPI/msgbuffer.pxi", line 93, in mpi4py.MPI.message_basic (d:\build\mpi4py\mpi4py-2.0.0\src\mpi4py.MPI.c:29448)
KeyError: 'O'
```

Any help will be much appreciated. I am stuck in this problem for a long time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `dtype=object`.

Mpi4py provides two kinds of communication functions, those whose names begin with an upper-case letter, e.g. `Scatter`, and those whose names begin with a lower-case letter, e.g. `scatter`. [From the Mpi4py documentation:](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/mpi4py.html)

> In MPI for Python, the Bcast(), Scatter(), Gather(), Allgather() and Alltoall() methods of Comm instances provide support for collective communications of memory buffers. The variants bcast(), scatter(), gather(), allgather() and alltoall() can communicate generic Python objects.

What is not clear from this is that even though numpy arrays supposedly expose memory buffers, the buffers apparently need to be to one of a small set of primitive data types, and certainly don't work with generic objects. Compare the following two pieces of code:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy

Comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
Size = Comm.Get_size()
Rank = Comm.Get_rank()

if Rank == 0:
    Data = numpy.empty(Size, dtype=object)
else:
    Data = None

Data = Comm.scatter(Data, 0) # I work fine!

print("Data on rank %d: " % Rank, Data)
```

and

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy

Comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
Size = Comm.Get_size()
Rank = Comm.Get_rank()

if Rank == 0:
    Data = numpy.empty(Size, dtype=object)
else:
    Data = None

Datb = numpy.empty(1, dtype=object)

Comm.Scatter(Data, Datb, 0) # I throw KeyError!

print("Datb on rank %d: " % Rank, Datb)
```

Unfortunately, Mpi4py provides no `scatterv`. From the same place in the docs:

> The vector variants (which can communicate different amounts of data to each process) Scatterv(), Gatherv(), Allgatherv() and Alltoallv() are also supported, they can only communicate objects exposing memory buffers.

These are not exceptions to the upper- vs lower-case rule for dtypes, either:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy

Comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
Size = Comm.Get_size()
Rank = Comm.Get_rank()

if Rank == 0:
    Data = numpy.empty(2*Size+1, dtype=numpy.dtype('float64'))
else:
    Data = None

if Rank == 0:
    Datb = numpy.empty(3, dtype=numpy.dtype('float64'))
else:
    Datb = numpy.empty(2, dtype=numpy.dtype('float64'))

Comm.Scatterv(Data, Datb, 0) # I work fine!

print("Datb on rank %d: " % Rank, Datb)
```

versus

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy

Comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
Size = Comm.Get_size()
Rank = Comm.Get_rank()

if Rank == 0:
    Data = numpy.empty(2*Size+1, dtype=object)
else:
    Data = None

if Rank == 0:
    Datb = numpy.empty(3, dtype=object)
else:
    Datb = numpy.empty(2, dtype=object)

Comm.Scatterv(Data, Datb, 0) # I throw KeyError!

print("Datb on rank %d: " % Rank, Datb)
```

You'll unfortunately need to write your code so that it can use `scatter`, necessitating the same `SendCount` for each process, or more primitive,  point-to-point communication functions, or use some parallel facility other than Mpi4py.

Using Mpi4py 2.0.0, the current stable version at the time of this writing.